# Order properties of the empty relation on the empty set, and a related question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, relations

**Context / Disclosure on the Origins of the Question:**

My question is motivated by [an MSE question posted earlier today](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059186/for-the-relation-r-%E2%88%85-on-is-it-reflexive-symmetric-transitive-asymmetric) which ultimately was closed. I was thinking about it when it was posted, just for its own sake: I never contended with relations on the empty set in my coursework, and vacuous logic was always something I felt I had a tenuous understanding of at best. So I wanted to make sure my own personal understanding of the question was okay, plus it also made me think of a related question which I ask here.

While I understand that usually reposting previously-closed questions is frowned upon, I feel like [in the spirit of this post on Meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29543/re-asking-another-users-on-hold-question), my elaborations and attempts might make me reposting this question worthwhile, and useful for people who come by in the future.

Below, I employ a more proper formulation of the question (that being which of the four properties the empty relation has), and ask a question based on some of the results I saw.

---

**Formulation of the Question:**

Since the empty set is a subset of every set, i.e. $\emptyset \subseteq \emptyset$, we can consider the empty relation on the empty set. In studying relations, there are four particular properties we're interested in.

> **Definitions:** Let $R$ be a relation on a set $S$, i.e. $R \subseteq S \times S:$. Then we define four properties of $R$ by the following:
>
> - *Reflexivity:* $\forall x \in S, (x,x) \in R$
> - *Transitivity:* $\forall x,y,z \in S, (x,y), (y,z) \in R \implies (x,z) \in R$
> - *Symmetry:* $\forall x,y \in S, (x,y) \in R \iff (y,x) \in R$
> - *Anti-Symmetry:* $\forall x,y \in S, (x,y), (y,x) \in R \iff x=y$

With that in mind, we want to see which of these properties the empty relation on the empty set has.

---

**My Attempts:**

For ease in notation, we let $R$ be the empty relation on $\emptyset$, i.e. $R \subseteq \emptyset \times \emptyset = \emptyset$.

Each proof follows through vacuous logic. To my understanding, we can look at each definition from before as an "if *this* then *that*" statement - symbolically, $P \implies Q$. If $P$ is always false, then the overall statement is always true, and thus the definition satisfied. So we investigate each property in that light:

- *Reflexivity:* Since there exists no $x \in \emptyset$, there is no element $x$ such that $(x,x) \not \in R$. Thus, vacuously, $R$ is reflexive.
- *Transitivity:* Similarly, there exists no $(x,y), (y,z) \in R$, so for all such pairs $(x,z) \in R$. Thus, vacuously, $R$ is transitive.
- *Symmetry:* For every $(x,y) \in R$, none of which exist, we cannot say there is no $(y,x) \in R$. Therefore, vacuously, $R$ is symmetric.
- *Anti-Symmetric:* There are no $(x,y), (y,x) \in R$, and therefore, for all such pairs, vacuously $x=y$ and $R$ is anti-symmetric.

---

**My Questions:**

- Are the above proofs, if not fully formal, at least in the right line of thinking? Are there any particular errors?
- I noticed that, if so, the empty relation is both symmetric and anti-symmetric. Intuitively, I feel like this is almost self-contradicting (but that's probably an issue in the terminology). Is this a particularly common property for relations that *don't* involve the empty set and aren't artificially constructed to be this way? I know that [per Alessandro Codenotti's answer to this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1475354/can-a-relation-be-both-symmetric-and-antisymmetric-or-neither) the equality relation is both antisymmetric and symmetric. [A post on Physics Forums](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/an-example-of-a-relation-that-is-symmetric-and-anti-symmetric.806808/) indicates that the only relations which are both symmetric and antisymmetric where $S$ is nonempty are relations
  $$R = \{(x,x) | x \in S \} \subseteq S \times S$$
  This would suggest such relations $R$ are very rare, and not entirely interesting or useful (aside from the aforementioned equality relation). Is this really the case? Do no other such relations exist for nonempty $S$? If so, how would one show that? (Showing this $R$ is indeed both is trivial. Showing no other such $R$ exist ... I'm not sure how to do that.)

Comment: I would argue that the relation = is extremely interesting and useful

Comment: Well, I meant moreso relations *other* than the equality relation.

Comment: in the second question, do you search for symmetry and anti-symmetry relation, or a relation that satisfy all of the properties?(mainly talking about reflexivity)

Comment: Just the two symmetry properties is fine.

Comment: Why aren't people upvoting this question?

Comment: "I noticed that, if so, the empty relation is both symmetric and anti-symmetric. Intuitively, I feel like this is almost self-contradicting (but that's probably an issue in the terminology)". You correctly gauged that this is just terminology. For another example and an advice, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/586817/a-function-cant-be-oddeven-they-said-right/586824#586824).

Comment: To add to @GitGud , it is possible for a set to be both closed and open together ([clopen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clopen_set))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, when you consider an all-quantified property like $\forall x\in S [ P(x)]$, where $P$ is a predicate in $x$, the assertion is defined as
$$\forall x(x\in S\Rightarrow P(x)).$$
The truth-table for the implication, $\Rightarrow$, says that if the premise is false (such as $x\in\emptyset$), then the whole statement is true. That's the thing behind your reasoning.

Answer (score 1):

First, anti-symmetry relation means $(a,b),(b,a)\in R\implies a=b$, it is not if and only if there.

There are more relations that are symmetry and anti-symmetry (exercise, prove that if a relation is both of those, it is also transitive)

For example, let $R$ be relation on $\Bbb N$ such that $(a,b)\in R\iff a=b=0$.

That being said, if $R$ on $A$ relation that satisfy those 2 properties, then $(a,b)\in R\implies a=b$, because $(a,b)\in R\implies (b,a)\in R\implies a=b$.

This way you can also see that adding reflexivity than the only relation is $=$.

Because $(a,a)\in R$ for all $a\in A$, so $=\subseteq R$, but also $(a,b)\in R\implies a=b$, so $R\subseteq =$, thus they are one and the same.